# Spacing around text in textfield

Tags: codenameone

[image: UI I am bulding]I am trying to mimic a JavaFX program (see attached image) that I've already implemented for my client.  He wants the same look for consistency.

How do I increase the space around the username and password text in the TextFields?

Comment: As a side note this UI should be pretty easy to mimic in Codename One. I don't see anything explicitly challenging here. I would avoid a `ComboBox` though and use a `Picker` instead to give a more native feel to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Style your TextField UIID to have padding of about 2mm.

[image]